# How can I search exactly match by full text?

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, contains

I have this Code

```
Select [Field]
From [TBL]
where contains( [Field] , '"Tel: Come"' )
```

but Result is:

```
Tel: Come <br/>
Tel Come
```

I need just show me: Tel: Come (exactly Match Searching) also if I search for "Tel Come", Result is both.

Please help me fix it so that the result is ONLY WHOLE MATCH.

Comment: Do you mean `=` not `CONTAINS`? Characters like `:` aren't indexed in a full text index.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to find rows which have the exact text `'Tel: Come'` then a full-text index isn't going to be what your after. A Full-Text Index isn't for such things, it's for finding words, not phrases, and doesn't index characters like `:`.

You can, therefore, use a `LIKE`, but you won't get the benefit of the indexes:

```
SELECT [Field]
FROM [TBL]
WHERE [Field] LIKE '%Tel: Come%';
```

Comment: yes, I know this, with LIKE and % also it result "Tel: comeon" before I wrote a code with LIKE and 4 Conditions to use SPACE befor and after SEARCH, also Space only Befor, only After, and without Space, But if Search Text be First Or End of a Line, Result not find it

Comment: its important because REPLACE, my customer want search "Tel: Come" then replace it with "Tel Come"

Comment: Are *sure* about that, @حامدصداقت ..? [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0d629008d01346094c6ff9be95070341)

Comment: You never use `REPLACE` in your query, @حامدصداقت ... Are you not giving us the full picture here?

Comment: I manage it by vb.net, We have 3 options on search form
1. any part: I use Like %Search%
2. Start With: I Use * at end of Contains
3.Whole Word
This one has 2 Part
A. Ignore Noise Word that is ok
B. Dont Ignore Noise Word ( I need Help for this Part )
Exactly Whole Match 
With Contains or Like not diffrent

Comment: dear, just tel me whats the code for whole word search in sql nvarchar(max)
with LIKE or any other things

Comment: I've already showed you how to use `LIKE` in the answer @حامدصداقت . Also, please don't call me "dear"; I'm not your wife/husband.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a full match, then you can use:

```
Select [Field]
From [TBL]
where [Field] = 'Tel: Come'
```

This can make use of a *regular* index on `[Field]`.  Getting an exact match using full text search is rather tricky; for instance, things like multiple spaces together are ignored.

Comment: Thanks, but my field has more text: abc def Tel: com def ghy , .... with = in where it didn't find any record